# Cargar un arreglo en un datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

[image: I get it from server then ... i wanna load this on datatable]

[image: I declared my datatable]

Deseo cargar un arreglo preparado desde el servidor en un datatable usando ajax url load,  pero me arroja un error con el formato json aparentemente. En las imagenes dejo la. Forma en la cual estoy declarando la tabla,  y lo que esta retornando de  servidor.

`$('#tblComponent').DataTable().ajax.url( data.requestdetail ).load();`

Culquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: Ok hecho.. Aunque las imagenes son descriptivas.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

En tu respuesta JSON creo que hay un campo que en tu dataTable no esta declarado `(nIdRow)`, para que DataTable funcione correctamente con peticiones Ajax debe tener la misma cantidad de datos.

Saludos